# Python Reformat Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, tabula

I am trying to iterate through the dataframe and if the row's value `Age` column is empty, it will move the value in `Name` column to the `Location` column of the previous row. Is there a quick way to do this?

**As-Is**

[image: As-Is Dataframe]

**To-Be**

[image: To-Be Dataframe]

Comment: Please post your source sample as code, it will make it a lot easier for people to solve.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy`:

```
arr = df.to_numpy()
arr[::2, -1] = arr[1::2,0]
df = pd.DataFrame(arr[::2], columns=df.columns)
```

Output:

```
      Name Age Location
0    Amber  21    North
1      Max  23    South
2  Jackson  38     East
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that works by iterating over the rows and copying the row's `Name` value to the previous row's `Location` value. Note this will break if the first row's `Age` is empty.

I'm pretty sure there's a more efficient way of dropping the empty rows at the end, so I welcome edits!

```
d = {'Name': ["Amber", "North", "Max", "South", "Jackson", "East"], 'Age': ["21", "", "23", "", "38", ""], "Location":["","","","","",""]}
df = pandas.DataFrame(data=d)

rows_to_drop = []

for index, values in df.iterrows():

    if not values["Age"]:

        df["Location"][index-1] = df["Name"][index]
        rows_to_drop.append(index)

df = df.drop(rows_to_drop)
```